# Find folder path for file

Tags: batch-file

I have folder tree, were in each folder there are some files (.xls or .CSV). I want to know path of that file and need to create folder on system date in that. and move file to concern folder. And next time when that script will run it will check only till old folder and will not check folder having SYStemdate.

Here is the code which I created but stuck(ACC is the path which is not fix for Subfolders.).

```
@Echo Off
::Variable for folder path
::Set AAC= d:\A\CC
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do Echo AA %%i

::for /r D:\A\CC %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="Lists.txt" set AAC=%%~dpa
Echo As %i%

:: SDate=DAYMONTHYEAR FORMAT of Systemdate
set SDate=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%

if not exist %i%\%SDate% mkdir %i%\%SDate%

move %i%\* %i%\%SDate%

::for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir d:\%Folder% /b /s') do copy "%%a %%b\*" "%Folder%\%SDate%\*
::for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir d:\A\*.txt /b /s') do set Ag=%%a

set "AAC="
Echo Now %AAC%
```

Comment: `::` means comment out. Lots of commands are commented out, so your script is not doing much. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Yes that is commented out as I was trying some different combinations. My requirement is.
My Files are saved in some folder Folder structure is e.g. d:\A\AA and inside that AA I have multiple subfolders now what I want is Script should check all subfolders and move file from that subfolder to new Folder(created inside of respective Subfolder and name is on systemdate).
New folder path- d:\A\AA\(Subfolder)\14022017(Sys Date)

Comment: If you want to regain control of your question, in order to be able to edit or comment on it, you can register an account and then request to have your accounts merged. Then you can go to https://superuser.com/contact selecting "I need to merge accounts" and enter the old and new account links. For your information your two accounts are https://superuser.com/users/707341/ashu and https://superuser.com/users/707346/ashu